# Unknown event structure (0) error in empty project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I try to create build for Android from empty project, but every time when I run the app it throws lots of

> Unknown event structure (0)

errors.
I use adb for debugging.

[Here is full log](http://pastebin.com/k6arPgNV)

I have already tried it in Unity 5.3.2, 5.3.3 and 5.3.4 and got the same result.

How do I fix it?

Comment: What Android version? What is your Minimum API set to in the Unity Android Settings? Are you sure this is an empty project....No script attached anywhere?

Comment: my device has android 4.2.2, minimum version is 2.3.3. And yeah, there are no scripts

Comment: Change the minimum api to 17 then try it again. If that didn't solve the problem then download the latest unity 5.4 like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try Unity [5.4.0B15](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta). This will likely fix the problem.

Comment: you know, the problem is gone, i don't see that error message in log, but now the app does not work, it just throws me to the mobile desktop, it seems that it happens when the error message tries to appear

Comment: @user2686299 The error was gone after updating Unity or Changing the API? "but now the app does not work, it just throws me to the mobile desktop" I don't understand....

Comment: after updating Unity. Sry for my bad eng, I meant that after launching the app it's hiding after 1 sec

Comment: @user2686299 the error went away after updating. but now it is crashing after 1 second?

Comment: @user2686299 create a simple scene with a simple textbox then try it. If it still crashes, provvide the model number of the Android device

Comment: JY-G2F, btw I use firmware MIUI-4.8.29

Comment: @user2686299 It is one those phones made by unknown companies. It is either running a customized version of Android ROM or it is missing some features. It's not Unity's fault. There is a problem with your phone.

Comment: seems like truth, on bluestacks' emulator it works fine

Comment: @user2686299 Some companies don't follow the Google recommended Android ROM and firmware standard leading to stuff like this. Only buy phones that are made by famous companies or things like this will happen.